# How to Record Audio in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording

I need to permanently save a voice message on physical media.  I purchased the cables and adapters to connect my cell phone's 2.5mm audio jack to one of my PC's 3.5mm audio jacks.  Should I just use the line-in or would another jack be better?  Should I use the headphone jack on my Logitech speakers?

Then, how do I configure Windows, or what application do I use, to record the audio?

Comment: I'm interested to see what cables and adapters you bought

Comment: @Revolter: I've had a cable like this ( http://www.amazon.com/Mediabridge-Stereo-design-accomodates-smartphone/dp/B004LTEUDO/ ) for years.  I recently purchased this ( http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2603246 ) adapter to complete the stated task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line-in would probably be the best match - a Mic-in would probably be overloaded by the signal. Once connected you may have to play the message a few times and experiment with the volume control on the phone to get the best level for an undistorted, clear recording.

Windows 7 has 'sound recorder' under the *All Programs..Accessories* menu, or you could have fun with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) - it's free to download and use.

Comment: Audacity would be a great solution.

Comment: Linker, thanks!  Audacity isn't the most user-friendly program out there, but after a bit of poking around I found that it has a lot of nice bells and whistles.